# If $a$ is an element of a group $g$ and$|a|= 7$ show that $a$ is the cube of some element of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a$ is an element of a group $G$ and$|a|= 7$ show that $a$ is the cube of some element of $G$.
I can't find relation ship between $|a|=7$ and why it must be cube of some element. Anyone can give me hint for this problem ?

Comment: Hint:  look for a "cube root" in the group generated by $a$.

Comment: Does $|a|$ stand for the order of $a$ in $G$ in your question ?

Comment: Hint: If it is true it must be true for the subgroup generated by $a$ which satisfies the conditions for $G$

Comment: @Astyx in textbook I does not tell anything about |a| is order or absolute value,but I think it's order

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Find $k$ such that $a=(a^k)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $a^7 = e$, so $a = a^m$ for any $m\equiv 1\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the cyclic group $\langle a \rangle $ the map $a \mapsto a^3$ is an automorphism.